# Programmatically add URL shortcut

Tags: android

Is it possible to programmatically add an icon to the desktop with a URL shortcut from my application?

Comment: Currently your question is a little confusing. What desktop?

Comment: Homescreen of the android device

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, can you add a Launcher icon programmatically that will act like a URL shortcut? Yes, use the [InstallShortCutReceiver source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/blob/master/src/com/android/launcher/InstallShortcutReceiver.java) from Launcher2 as a guide.